# Aligning text next to an image (left side)

Tags: html, css, text

The issue I'm having is putting text on the left side of an image...

HTML & CSS

```css
h2,
social-hand {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 95px;
}

p {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 95px;
  margin-right: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-hand"><img src="social-hand.jpg">
  <h2><big>Tittle Text</big></h2>
</div>
<p>Example Text <a href="About.html">Read More ></a>
</p>
```

[**And this is the result I'm getting...**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXKBJ.png)

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Hi, which text exactly would you like to be displayed to the left of the image?

Comment: Try using display:block; instead

Answer (score 0):

Try using display block instead:

```css
h2, social-hand {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 95px;
 }
 
 p {
    margin-left: 95px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;    
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-hand"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <h2><big>Tittle Text</big></h2>
    </div>
    <p>Example Text   <a href="About.html">Read More ></a>
    </p>
```